# How to make a wrapper<int> class with a converting constructor win against wrapper<double> in overload resolution?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, overload-resolution

I'm trying to design a wrapper to tackle arithmetic params with some special logic.

https://godbolt.org/z/zG959e5Pz

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T>
struct wrapper {
    wrapper(const T& o): value(o) {}
    T value;
};

void func(wrapper<int> a) {
    printf("int: %d\n", a.value);
}


int main () {
    func(1); // int: 1
    func(1.0); // int: 1
}
```

However, when I declare an overload function for `func`, I meet a compile error. It seem that the compiler cannot choose a concrete overloaded func.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

template <class T>
struct wrapper {
    wrapper(const T& o): value(o) {}
    T value;
};

void func(wrapper<int> a) {
    printf("int: %d\n", a.value);
}

void func(wrapper<double> a) {
    printf("double: %.2f\n", a.value);
}

int main () {
    func(1);
    // func(1.1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YEo4c3E69

the compiler error

```cpp
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:18:9: error: call of overloaded 'func(int)' is ambiguous
   18 |     func(1);
      |     ~~~~^~~
<source>:9:6: note: candidate: 'void func(wrapper<int>)'
    9 | void func(wrapper<int> a) {
      |      ^~~~
<source>:13:6: note: candidate: 'void func(wrapper<double>)'
   13 | void func(wrapper<double> a) {
      |      ^~~~
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The value `1` could be implicitly converted to either `wrapper<int>` *or* `wrapper<double>`. Which one should the compiler choose? It can't, so it tells you that the call is ambiguous to let you solve it.

Comment: By the way, how is the error mentioned in the title related to the errors you actually ask about?

Comment: On a different (and unrelated) note, please don't use the old C function `printf` to print output. It's rather complicated with its formats, and not type-safe.

Comment: I don't understand the point of `wrapper`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why it could be tho? `1` is `int` literal, so converting it to `wrapper<double>` requires two conversions.

Comment: Terminology: there is no such thing as an implicit cast. There are implicit and explicit *conversions*. A cast is an explicit conversion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So as the title tells, how to avoid implicit cast from `double` to `int`? Or no solutions ?

Comment: @molbdnilo It confuse me that how may steps in the conversion from double to wrapper<int>

Comment: @xujh There's no conversion from `double` to `wrapper<int>`, but there is one from `int` to `wrapper<double>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the constructor a template, accepting any type. Then reject types other than `T` with SFINAE. This will prevent implicit argument conversions when calling it.

```
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
struct wrapper {
    template <std::same_as<T> U = T>
    wrapper(const U &o): value(o) {}
    T value;
};
```

Or pre-C++20:

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper {
    template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
    wrapper(const U &o): value(o) {}
    T value;
};
```

Comment: How come this is necessary in the first place? `const int&` binding to an `int` is merely a qualification conversion, so the conversion sequence should be better than converting `int` to `double` and then binding `const double&` to it.

Comment: @JanSchultke No idea, might be worth a separate question. I was also surprised that the alternative solution of adding a `wrapper(const auto &) = delete;` didn't work.

Comment: I agree, it does make for a good [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77156923/5740428).

Comment: The deleted overload **is** a candidate function, even if deleted.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm intentionally using this form of SFINAE. Pre-C++20 it's the only form that's completely fool-proof - using `int` means one can instantiate the function multiple times by passing different numbers, while `nullptr_t` has only one possible value.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat fair point, it didn't occur to me that there could be a deeper meaning behind this; sorry for the edit. It's quite unfortunate that there is no alternative for constructors which would avoid having an extra template parameter completely.

Comment: I have a similar problem but the solution above no longer applies, may you assist me look at it? https://godbolt.org/z/vGca3enzs. `explicit` is not what was hoped for.