# Why does a better standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion not make an overload better?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

This is a follow-up question to [how to avoid implicit cast from `double` to `int`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77156456/5740428). Say I have the following code:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct wrapper {
    wrapper(const T&);
};

void f(wrapper<int>);

void f(wrapper<double>);

int main () {
    f(1); // error: ambiguous call to overloaded function
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5WsqvPjc3); note that the behavior is the same for all major compilers*

How come `f(1)` is ambiguous? There are two conversion sequences:

- `1` -> `const int&` via qualification conversion and reference binding -> `wrapper<int>` via converting constructor
- `1` -> `const double&` via floating point conversion, temporary materialization, qualification conversion, and reference binding -> `wrapper<double>` via converting constructor

The first conversion sequence looks better, so how come the first overload doesn't win?

Comment: Both sequences end in a user defined conversion. That ranks the whole sequnce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire implicit conversion sequence consists of a user-defined conversion sequence:

> A well-formed implicit conversion sequence is one of the following forms:
>
> - a [standard conversion sequence](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.scs),
> - a [user-defined conversion sequence](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.user), or
> - an [ellipsis conversion sequence](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.ellipsis).

- [[over.best.ics.general] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics.general#3)

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion followed by a second standard conversion sequence.

- [[over.ics.user] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.user#1)

The standard conversion sequence `int -> const int&` is better than `int -> const double&`, however, this is not considered. Both user-defined conversion sequences `int -> wrapper<int>` and `int -> wrapper<double>` are equally ranked by [[over.ics.rank] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#2), and the only distinction between user-defined conversion sequences in [[over.ics.rank] p3.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.3) applies to the **second** standard conversion only.

Contrary to intuition:

- A conversion `wrapper<int> -> int` would be better than `wrapper<int> -> double` if `wrapper<T>` had an `operator T` conversion function.
- However, the conversions `int -> wrapper<int>` and `int -> wrapper<double>` are equally ranked.